# Why won't this textbox update its value? c#

Tags: c#, textbox, messagebox

I am trying to get some textboxes to update their values when I call this function.  I can't get them to update their values, but if I call a messagebox right below with the same variable that I send to them, THEY DO UPDATE THEIR VALUES.

I have no idea what is causing this.  Any ideas?

```
private void updateCurrentCharacterInfoLabels()
    {
        ProgressBox.set(Crafter.MyCurrentInfo.CurrentProgress);
        MessageBox.Show(Crafter.MyCurrentInfo.CurrentProgress.ToString());
        ProgressBox.Invalidate();
        QualityBox.set(Crafter.MyCurrentInfo.CurrentQuality);
        MessageBox.Show(Crafter.MyCurrentInfo.CurrentQuality.ToString());
        QualityBox.Invalidate();
        DurabilityBox.set(Crafter.MyCurrentInfo.CurrentDurability);
        MessageBox.Show(Crafter.MyCurrentInfo.CurrentDurability.ToString());
        DurabilityBox.Invalidate();
```

When I comment out the MessageBox.Show() parts, the form doesn't update the textbox values at all.  When I keep them in, it updates perfectly.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: Yes, I call it once each cycle.  I have been debugging and verified that the program does cycle through this function each time.  The Crafter.MyCurrentInfo variables are all showing the correct values in memory.  But the Custom textboxes never updated to these values until I added in the MessageBox.Show(..) statements

Comment: It is called about once every 20 seconds.  I have tried adding System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50) calls in place of the MessageBox to see if it just needed a pause there, but that failed.  Even stepping through step by step doesn't allow the boxes to update w/o the messagebox fix

Answer (score 0):

So, I was able to get the boxes to update by calling .Refresh() on each one of them.  I thought .Invalidate() did that, but I guess not.

Calling the messageBox.Show() must have led to the form refreshing itself.  I think its strange that other things on the form were updating themselves throughout, but it never redrew these boxes.  Is it because they were custom Textboxes?